# Falling bricks building the walls of a house

Tags: animation

I want to build a house animation from ground up to the roof.
Is there a way to automate falling bricks that are building the walls of a house? I thought about the buildup-modifier, but the modifier only builds up polygon per polygon.
Im using Blender 2.8.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I would try using making a rigid body simulation, upside down so that the bricks are animated to fall down from your model. Then, once the animation is baked, flip it 180d so that it is oriented correctly. Finally, play the animation backwards. If you want it to be layer-by-layer, you would have to find a way to bake each layer individually (If your bricks are individual objects, just select each layer to animate and play them in the right order).